# Xamarin Mvvmcross slow startup dll loading

Tags: performance, plugins, dll, xamarin, mvvmcross

Loading dll files at startup is taking 3.5 seconds in our app. Does anyone know how can we reduce this time? Is it possible to delay plugins dll loading? 
We are using Xamarin and Mvvmcross.

Comment: Xamarin.iOS or Xamarin.Android? And how did you measure this?

Comment: We encounter the problem especially on iOS, iPhone 4, iPhone 4s. And we measured it with traces in our log.

Answer (score 2):

In Xamarin.iOS all dlls are loaded at startup before your code is executed, so I don't think you measured dll loading time, but something else that might look like it.

Without more data it would be mere speculation to say anything, so I recommend you use Instruments with the Time Profiler to see exactly what happens at startup and where the time goes.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the app in debug mode you can see the initialization in the output window, and there you can see the libraries being loaded.
May be is not exactly the same process when you run the compiled app, but I think is probable that the delay in the startup is due to this initialization.